# logging data when using crontab

Tags: raspbian, python, cron, logfiles

**Edits:** added comments to code.

I am running a small .py script on my Raspberry Pi with a DHT11 sensor and 3 LEDs.
I am starting the program on boot with crontab, and everything is running fine apart from the logging of the data.

First of all, the temp.py script:

```
#The needed imports
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_DHT
import time
import logging

#setting up the GPIO pins
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)


print("Running temp")

#my original logging config for when i execute the .py file my self
#logging.basicConfig(filename='temp.log', level=logging.INFO, 
      #format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

#the logging config i have tried, so i am not forcing where its logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')


while True:
        #records the humidity and temperature and sets them as hum and temp 
        hum, temp = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT11, 4)
        print(hum, temp)
        GPIO.output(16, False)
        GPIO.output(20, False)
        GPIO.output(21, False)

        #turns on LED to show the temp within range
        if int(temp) > 23:
                GPIO.output(16, True)
        if int(temp) < 24 and int(temp) > 19:
                GPIO.output(20, True)
        if int(temp) < 20:
                GPIO.output(21, True)

        #and here i do the actual logging
        logging.info('temp: ' + str(temp) + '  |||  hum: ' + str(hum))
        time.sleep(60)
```

So, when I run the temp.py manually (`sudo python temp.py`) and use the ORIGINAL logging config, it all works fine and I get an output in temp.log

Now, when I try and run my script with crontab:

`@reboot sudo python share/temp.py >> share/temp.log 2>&1`

the script runs fine, I get the visual output as expected, the temp.log file is created, but I get NO output in the temp.log, nor any errors.

As I stated above, I have tried to use filename='' and leave it out, no difference.

I have tried to, in the crontab to add:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

but that did nothing (it's not really a bash file anyway)

I have tried to just write:

@reboot sudo python share/temp.py > share/temp.log
still nothing.

As I have said, the logfile temp.log is created everytime, I just get no output.

As a last resort, I tried to remove the temp.log (`sudo rm temp.log`) while the script was running, after it had created the initial temp.log, and it never recreated another temp.log, it just kept running.

Does anyone have any idea to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @reboot sudo python share/temp.py >> share/temp.log &

Comment: @AndyAnderson don't work sadly :/

Comment: Okay, i have found that if i change my crontab to: @reboot sudo python share/temp.py > share/temp.txt it works like a charm.

Comment: If you want to redirect stderr to stdout then your redirection is wrong. It must be `2>&1` not `2&>1`. You found the solution so please answer your question.

Comment: @Ingo - yes you are right. It was a typo and i have now corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: **just use a .txt** :)

Through a bit of trial and error, a whole lot of google searches and some help in here i found the following:

I never managed to be able to write what i wanted to a .log file when using crontab's @reboot option.

What i found was the fact that you could just write to a .txt file instead and you would get all the output you wanted.

```
@reboot sudo python yourPath/fileName.py >> yourPath/fileName.txt 2>&1
```

why this is so, i have no idea. But if you don't especially want a .log file, just a log over your prints or whatever, **just use a .txt** :)

**Edit:** i am just adding this part just in case someone new as me comes across this post.
To see your prints/logs in real time while the program is running use **tail FileName.txt** it shows the last few lines in the document. To get a constant update use **tail -f FileName.txt** it will update as soon as the txt is updated.